# App Icons in Xcode Summary appear to be tiny

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, retina-display

I've got icons for my app which I've been using for a year. I'm working on an update to the app and since Xcode has changed so much since I last wrote this app, I want to start with a fresh project to get updated build settings, etc. I'm currently using Xcode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a).

When I drag and drop my icon files into the Summary tab, they appear to be tiny! What's wrong?

[image]

Here are the icons, they are 57x57 and 114x114 pngs.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's is your current Xcode version?

Comment: Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a)

Comment: hmm no answer...? i assume the icons still work as you'd expect when you run your app?

Comment: They appear to work properly, yes. I'm worried about what happens when I submit though.

Answer (score -1):

try dragging and dropping actual file from Finder, it will get the images created for you and will let you know if there are any issues with the files.

Comment: There are two ways, try dragging from the project tree then.